# Django CreateView filter foreingkey

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

i need some help. I'm writting an app with django 1.6 and python 3.4.

My models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    level = models.IntegerField()
    parent_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, null=True, blank=True)
```

My View:

```
class InvoiceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Account
    template_name = 'account/templates/create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account_list')
```

Then when i create a new Account a dropdown list appear to select the Parent Account, everything fine, but i want to fill that dropdown list to accounts with level equal to 2 (example), not with all accounts.

something like this:

```
account.object.all().filter(level=2)
```

thanks for advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom form and set the form_class variable in your view like:

```
class InvoiceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Account
    form_class = AccountForm
    template_name = 'account/templates/create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account_list')
```

In your form, (I've named it AccountForm), you can define the parent field as desired:

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta(object):
    model = Account

  parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Account.objects.filter(level=2))
```

Comment: thanks, i have an error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Comment: Great!! The only way is using a Form class, not?

Comment: This is the simplest way. The default form inherits the behavior using model definition, if you need some customization to that, you need to define a custom form.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
account_list = account.objects.filter(level=2)
```

The Django Documentation on [making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/) also answers that question quite well.